# XCode 4 Show Files With Matching Names shortcut

Tags: xcode, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts

XCode 4 (I use 4.3.3) has nice feature - in the bottom of most navigator panels (left panel) it has search field where you can write match expression to quick find entity you need. But I have not found any way to switch to this field from code area without using the mouse/trackpad.

Does anybody know a shortcut that calls in Preferences->Key Bindings ?

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Opens the project navigator and highlights the search bar, ready to type.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
Just opens the project navigator.

Comment: new favorite keyboard shortcut, been looking for this a long time!

Answer (score 7):

I use...

```
Command + Shift + O
```

This opens a dialog box where you can enter the required file name, it also does match expression.